# Can I enable cross site scripting in IE for any/all websites by simply disabling XSS filter- or is something more required?

Tags: security, xss, cross-site

I want to enable cross site scripting for some sites.  Specifically, I want to submit a web form to a 3rd party site, I have set the target iframe for the web form's response to a child iframe, now I want my code in main window to retrieve content of the response web page.

Am I correct in assuming that I can do the above by simply disabling the XSS Filter in Internet Explorer? Or is something else also required? Also how do I enable cross site scripting in Firefox (for the same scenario?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE's XSS filter does not protect against [DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).  So in order to execute a javascript payload across domains you can simply run `eval()` the request variable or use `document.write()`.

A more common approach is to use a "cross-domain proxy". Mainly because this approach usually doesn't introduce a gaping vulnerability which could be used to attack your users.

Comment: can you give some sample code that extracts the contents of the page in child iframe? Something that will work in IE? Thanks...

Comment: (1) The page whose content i want to obtain, is the response by a 3rd party site to a form submission that has been made to that site...In such case, can I use DOM based XSS? (2) If I do use DOM based XSS, wont that leave my site vulnerable to other ppl exploiting the same?

Comment: thanks a lot Rook, i didnt know ANYTHING about browser security :( your guide sure helps a lot...

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct in assuming that I can do the above by simply disabling the XSS Filter in Internet explorer?

No. The XSS filter isn't responsible for this limitation.

> Or is something else also required for the same?

There is no way to enable cross-origin requests from within a web page -- restrictions on cross-origin requests are a fundamental part of the web security model. However, for development, you can launch Google Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag to allow you to make cross-origin requests. This can be helpful in development of web applications where the application must access an API hosted on another domain.

Comment: just now i read on wikipedia-- "Headers added to a server's HTTP response headers can allow cross-domain requests to succeed. For example, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, can allow all domains to access a server. Access-Control-Allow-Origin can be used in all browsers that support cross-domain requests, which includes Internet Explorer 8. " However the form response (which I want to parse through) is for a 3rd party site over which I have no control-- in such case, even this approach cannot work...am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: Same-Origin Policy aside, XSS can be used to obtain content from another domain...

Comment: also, "XMLHttpRequest Level 2 also includes a feature to communicate with other domains" -- can this do the task that I want to do ( ie get web page contents from child iframe in browser)?

Comment: First comment: Your assumption is correct -- the target web site must allow you to perform cross-domain requests using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Similarly, cross-domain communication requires the other site's cooperation. If the other site isn't "cooperating", it is not possible to get content from it via JavaScript -- this is a purposeful security feature.