# Is there anyway to bypass IE11 xss filter?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, xss

I'm trying to do a proof-of-concept for a vulnerable website, but IE11 xss filter blocks my javascript from running.

Is there anyway to bypass it?
I'm researching about this but I can't seem to find a working payload.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129386/can-i-enable-cross-site-scripting-in-ie-for-any-all-websites-by-simply-disabling), it says *IE's XSS filter does not protect against [DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS). So in order to execute a javascript payload across domains you can simply run `eval()` the request variable or use `document.write()`*. There's [an article](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/dom-based-cross-site-scripting-vulnerability/) about DOM Based XSS with more detailed information, you could refer to it.

Besides, [Double Encoding](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding) can also bypass IE's XSS filter. You could check [this blog](https://osandamalith.com/2016/07/27/bypassing-ie-and-edge-xss-filters-with-double-encoding/) for detailed steps.